# possibly buying a used desktop computer?

Tags: upgrade

I have a question about a desktop I am very interested in purchasing that I have found.It is a dual core 3.9g,350 gig hardrive,cooler master case and this lady says it has 8.8 gigs of ram?I am taking a chance on it I know,in her ad she wanted 200 for it but when I called she dropped the price to 100.She says her husband used it at their company but upgraded to a newer system.My question is about the memory she claims is in it 8.8 gigs.I didnt know that physical memory read that way,lol.I m supposed to meet her tommorrow and I ve asked her about the psu,motherboard,socket and such but she claims she knows nothing about these things her husband does.If anyone can explain her memory interpretation to me it will make me feel a bit at ease.Thank you

Comment: What kind of a question is that to be?! Logically your answer lies in asking her husband, but don't bother, unless you want to waste your money!

Comment: you know I thought the same as you did.But it seems her husband is always busy.He is supposedly a big time engineer.I find it strange that the engineers are also allowed to build their own computers.I have also researched google for the answer to the memory question and am not coming up with it.Sorta hoping someone might know something here.When I get there I can take the cover off and get a better look but if I can get an answer on the memory question and it isnt favorable then I won t even have to waste the gas to get there

Comment: Please Read FAQ

Comment: @robert 
try other stackexchange for your question
this website for ubuntu only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ram does not come in 10ths.of gigabytes / proportions,  8.8 is not a possible calculation. Allow her to have you open the case and look at the memory modules.

Chances are 4 sticks of 2Gb = 8Gb total.

If running Linux then:

```
sudo lshw -c memory
```

Output should be something like this

```
*-memory                
  description: System memory
  physical id: 0
  size: 2013MiB <<<<<NOTE THE SIZE HERE = 2Gb
*-cache:0
  description: L1 cache
  physical id: 0
  size: 128KiB
*-cache:1
  description: L2 cache
  physical id: 1
  size: 256KiB
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer.I thought the same.I cant reach the husband and she isnt too technical.When I saw this I asked her about the motherboard and processors and she has no clue.In her pics where I saw this tower it is opened up.I guess I just have to see it close up.

Comment: Good luck with that. for a hundred you really can't go to wrong

Comment: I was thinking that to.While I was on the phone with her she dropped price to 100 and actually told me she is wanting to give me a gateway desktop for free.Lol I did tag it as upgrade and I am using it in ubuntu when I get it.cmon people be gentle,lol